# FaceBook IOS SDK - GitHub

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I start writing a simple app to use FaceBook IOS SDK from GitHub.

I have a few questions about it:

1. Is there a better documentation about those Delegate .. functions ? I cannot find those except the ones in DemoApp in the package
2. In the DemoApp, fbDidLogin, fbDidNotLogin and fbDidLogout are never called ... even a dialog is shown and I typed in username and password for logging in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finished my application with FaceBook SDK.Therefore, I can answer my own questions now.

1) Developer can follow the DemoApp OR can visit http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/how-to-develop-facebook-application-for-iphone/ for more information

2) fbDidLogin, fbDidNotLogin and fbDidLogout would only be called IF inline Dialog box (for FaceBook) is used. Those delegate functions won't be called IF FaecBook app or Safari browser is used instead